# How to monitor session values?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I am developing a web app. In that app, i am maintaining huge data map in the session. I deployed my app in Tomcat 6.0. Sometimes i am experincing heap space problem.

How to increase the heap space?
How do i maintain the session values?
How to track the values in the sesssion?

I am using netbeans 6.1 to develope the app. Is there any tool to monitor the session values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I am developing a web app. In that app, I am maintaining huge data map in the session

Well, that's maybe not a that good idea, especially if you keep data in the session for a long time:

- this won't scale well if you increase the number of concurrent users.
- this would have a huge cost in a clustered environment with persistent sessions (this might not be the case here but keep it in mind).

An alternative would be to write the data to a database.

> How to increase the heap space?

Use the `-Xmx` JVM option to set the max heap space. For example, `-Xmx512M`. With Tomcat, you are supposed to set the JVM options in the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable (I'd set it in catalina.bat). See [this blog post](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html).

> Is there any tool to monitor the session values?

[Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/) can do this (see the [changelog](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/latest.shtml)).

#### See also

- [Best Practice: Storing objects in HTTP sessions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/store_objects_in_httpsession.html)
- [Java theory and practice: State replication in the Web tier](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07294.html)
- [Recipe 2.3: Reducing HttpSession object size](http://www.precisejava.com/book/chapter2/reduce_session_size.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there an API : [HttpSessionAttributeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html)